# Tumblr photo posting by using jumblr

Tags: android, post, tumblr, jumblr

I am developing simple application to post text and a photo via `tumblr` by using [jumblr](https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr). Text posting is working perfectly. But image posting as file working but image posting by url is not working.

My code

```
                client = new JumblrClient(TumblrConstants.tumblrConsKey,
                        TumblrConstants.tumblrSecKey);
                client.setToken(objSession.getToken(),
                        objSession.getTokenSecret());
                // This part is working perfectly
                PhotoPost photoPost =client.newPost(client.user().getName(),
                        PhotoPost.class);
                File file=new File(picturePath);
                photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo(file));
                photoPost.save();

                // This part is not working
                PhotoPost photoPost1 = client.newPost(client.user().getName(),
                        PhotoPost.class);
                String imgUrl = "http://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff";
                photoPost1.setCaption("sample");
                //photoPost.setSource(imgUrl);
                photoPost1.setLinkUrl(imgUrl);
                photoPost1.save();

    //              TextPost post = client.newPost(client.user().getName(),
    //                      TextPost.class);
    //              post.setTitle("Sample title");
    //              post.setBody(txt);
    //              post.save();
```

Error:

```
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082): Caused by: org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service.
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:69)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:75)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at com.tumblr.jumblr.request.RequestBuilder.postMultipart(RequestBuilder.java:56)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at com.tumblr.jumblr.JumblrClient.postCreate(JumblrClient.java:352)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at com.tumblr.jumblr.types.Post.save(Post.java:331)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at com.selva.TumblrLogin$PublishPicture.doInBackground(TumblrLogin.java:445)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at com.selva.TumblrLogin$PublishPicture.doInBackground(TumblrLogin.java:1)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    ... 5 more
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentials(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at org.scribe.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:29)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at org.scribe.model.Request.doSend(Request.java:115)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    at org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:65)
01-22 16:25:44.929: E/AndroidRuntime(10082):    ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using jumblr - Tumblr java client

```
JumblrClient client = new JumblrClient(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY,Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET);

client.setToken(preferences.getString("token",null), preferences.getString("token_secret", null));

PhotoPost pp = client.newPost(client.user().getBlogs().get(0).getName(),PhotoPost.class);

pp.setCaption(caption);
// pp.setLinkUrl(link);
// pp.setSource(mImage); // String URL
pp.setPhoto(new Photo(imgFile));
pp.save();
```

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo("https://www.tablesavvy.com/img/big/nana-quail.jpg"));       same error coming again

Comment: Dear, instead of url you have to send file like 
File imgFile = new File(imagePath);
photoPost.setPhoto(new Photo(imgFile));

Comment: Sending as file working for me. But i need to send image as url. okay, i will tried setLinkUrl. It also gives same error.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to internet.

Comment: @Idce sending image as url (setLinkUrl) is not working. sending image as file is working.

Comment: Make sure you are connected to internet then after it will not work then create issue over here 
https://github.com/tumblr/jumblr

Comment: I am sending the images as file and as link at the same time with different instances. File type working. url not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create & save a new `PhotoPost` by URL with the following code once I authenticated.

```
final String source = "<YOUR IMAGE URL HERE>";
final PhotoPost post = client.newPost("<AUTHENTICATED BLOG NAME>", PhotoPost.class);
post.setSource(source);
post.save();
```